# VS Code React app closes/crashes using Chrome debugger

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am troubleshooting an issue I am having debugging a React application using VS Code with the Chrome debugger extension. I am using Windows 10 x64.

When I try to log into the application from the app's login page, the debug browser closes without any error (see screenshot below of break-point in code where the browser closes/crashes). I've tried debugging with both Chrome and Edge and I see the same issue with both browsers.
[image]

I do not have the same issue running the application without debugger from `npm start`. Nor do I see the issue when running the application from Chrome debugger on a different computer. Also my friend who is working on the same code does not see the issue on his computer when debugging or running the code.

I cloned an extra copy of the application code onto a different directory on my computer and that did not fix the issue.

I see a file is created `\src\debug.log` which seems like it could be related to the issue, but not sure what this is used for. The log file just shows the below error over and over.

> ERROR:crash_report_database_win.cc(469)] failed to stat report

Any ideas on how I can fix this or what might be happening here?

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems to be triggered by React Router's history object. We should open an issue on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues).

Comment: We should also open an issue on [microsoft/vscode-js-debug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues).

Comment: Same for me. It appeared ~1 week ago

Comment: angular here :(

Answer (score 3):

I faced with the same issue in the Chrome version 85, I've updated to version 86.0.4240.75 and now is working for me

Comment: I just spent the whole day trying to troubleshoot this issue. Shame I did not see the answer sooner. Also upgraded and it seems to have fixed the issue. I had the same problem in Edge (Chromium).

Answer (score 2):

Here you'll find the Chrome Bug Report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1123329

The solution for now is to disable the new Javascript Debugger

`"debug.javascript.usePreview": false`

[image: vscode settings screenshot]

Comment: Sometimes it happens even when the debugger is not attached.

Comment: Looks like they fixed it in Chrome 86 or 87. I switched to Canary, which is currently at 88, and now it works fine.